# How to check if the location is invalid or it does not have proper read/write permissions in Java

Tags: java, file, permissions, mkdir

This question is not for checking if an entered location is having sufficient permissions or not,
What I am trying to check is that:

1. Whether the given location is invalid?
2. Whether the given location is valid and it has proper permissions?

This is what I did:

```java
File LocationFileObj = new File(loactionToCheck);
if(LocationFileObj.exists()){
    if(Files.isWritable(LocationFileObj.toPath()) && Files.isReadable(LocationFileObj.toPath())){
        System.out.println("Location is valid and has permissions");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Location is valid and has no permissions");
    }
}
else{
    if(LocationFileObj.mkdirs()){
        System.out.println("Location is valid and has permissions");
    }
    else{
        //Need a check here [This is where issue comes]
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```

But as you can see,
If I enter "C:\AAA\BBB\CCC" [CCC is not created and is a new directory],
the whole "C:\AAA\BBB" has no permission for the user but is valid and exists.
I need to get the result as "No permission" instead of "Invalid".
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: If the `LocationFileObj` does not exist, you could check whether its parent exists (repeat recursively until existing parent is found) and if that is the case check its permissions. Though possibly there should also be a permission check after the directories have been created? This depends on the use case and the OS, but if for example the OS allows creating `C:\AAA\BBB\CCC`, but for whatever reason denies read and write access within `CCC` then that might be important to know. Also it would probably be good to consistently use `java.nio.file` since that will throw useful exceptions.

Comment: @Marcono1234 - Hi, yes I too thought of checking the parent directory is present recursively But is that the most optimal solution for this problem? Is there any other workarounds?
And if we are able to create directories, won't we have read and write permissions along with that, It is taken for granted right? or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't think of another way to solve this other than checking the permissions of the parent and then create the missing directories one by one (using `mkdir()` / `Files.createDirectory`). My previous comment might be partially incorrect, with `isReadable` / `isWritable` you are only checking the given path, but not its children. So you should always check this before trying to create a directory. E.g. under Windows I can create a folder where the user has only for that folder write access, but not any nested folders.